# using a for loop in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, for-loop, plsql

1. Write a PL/SQL program that accomplishes the following:
   (a) Declare a cursor  called c_students that selects the following fields:
   StudentId,  Lname,  Fname,  and Major from the Students table
   Where the major is ‘Accounting’
   (b) Retrieve the records listed above into v_sid, v_lname, v_fname, v_major
   (c) Display the retrieved records.

Use the for..  loop  to retrieve all the rows from the Student  table where the students last name is ‘Black’. Display these rows.

SOLUTION:
I have managed to complete parts a, b and c successfully as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS students;
CREATE TABLE students(
    StudentId NUMBER(3),
    LName VARCHAR2(30),
    FNAme VARCHAR2(30),
    Major VARCHAR2(30));
INSERT INTO students VALUES(130,'Black','Judy','Accounting');
INSERT INTO students VALUES(132,'Maw','Richard','Marketing');
INSERT INTO students VALUES(134,'Bessner','Bryan','Finance');
INSERT INTO students VALUES(136,'Shaw','Tim','Accounting');
INSERT INTO students VALUES(138,'Black','Conrad','Sales');

COMMIT;

DECLARE
    cursor c_students IS
    --for rec in (select * from students where 
        select * from students where major like 'Accounting';
    v_sid Number(3);
    v_lname VARCHAR2(30);
    v_fname VARCHAR2(30);
    v_major VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN   
    open c_students;
    Loop
        Fetch c_students into v_sid, v_lname, v_fname, v_major;
        IF c_students%NOTFOUND Then
            Exit;
        End If;
        dbms_output.put_line(v_sid||' '||v_lname||' '||v_fname||' '||v_major);
    End Loop;
    close c_students;
End;
/
```

=================================================================================

Now the last part, after c, states that I need to accomplish the same thing I did above with a for loop and I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it in a for loop. I know that the for-loop doesn't get declared and starts in the Begin section, but I don't know where to go from there. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: http://www2.cis.gsu.edu/dmcdonald/cis8040/Oracle%20Basics%20of%20PL_SQL.pdf  Page 32

Comment: OR http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_loops.htm

Comment: Or, if all else fails, [Try Reading The Manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/static.htm#CHDGIBHC).

Answer (score 1):

Replace the open loop etc with the following. Then you can reference your cursor's columns through the `rec` variable.

```
For rec in c_students
Loop
...
End loop;
```